# Restoring PostGIS 2.1. dump in PostGIS 2.2

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-3

I tryed to restore my old PostGIS dumps (Postgis 2.1, PostgreSQL 9.1) at my new system (PostGIS 2.2 and PostgreSQL 9.5)

I was using pgadmin3 to dump the databases and was now trying to restore it with pgadmin3 but got this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory
```

Do I have to downgrade my PostGIS-Version back to 2.1? Or is there a more elegant way?

Im working on a Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Comment: I used on the psql console "\i path-to-file" to restore a db that does not wanted to be restored with the pgadmin itself. No idea why, but you could try.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a PostGIS installation that was created by loading the `postgis.sql` file, rather than using the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` command. So when you dumped your database, you got not only the data, but also all the function definitions, which includes references to the 2.1 PostGIS library.

- Install PostGIS 2.1.8 on your new system.
- Create a blank database, do not add PostGIS.
- Do your restore. The function definitions in your dump file should find the PostGIS 2.1 library you've installed.
- Turn your unpackaged PostGIS into a packaged extension by running `CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION 2.1.8 FROM unpackaged`
- Install PostGIS 2.2.2 on your new system.
- Upgrade your PostGIS using the extension mechanism: `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO 2.2.2`

Or you could do the package-to-extension-and-update steps on your old database pre-dump, either way. The idea though is to get away from having the function definitions mixed in with the data by using the extension system, so you get clean dumps.

Comment: I don't know how to install PostGIS 2.1.8. I tryed with these instructions: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiInstall and got several errors. postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 packages are not available.